# Is Table_storage_by_organization view in BigQuery working for region-EU?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Recently, querying the [TABLE_STORAGE_BY_ORGANIZATION](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-table-storage-by-organization) view for **region-EU** has resulted in the following error:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Name last_metadata_refresh_timestamp not found inside l; failed to parse view 'region-eu.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE_BY_ORGANIZATION' at [29:7]
```

There are no leads or clues on what might be causing this problem. has anyone else faced a similar error?

Comment: Hi @Sathiya Sarathi, according to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-table-storage-by-organization#scope_and_syntax) you must specify the location to query the INFORMATION\_SCHEMA views and the location of the query execution must match the region of the INFORMATION\_SCHEMA view. For more information about this supporting regions please refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/locations).

Comment: @SushmaJeerahalli Thanks for pointing it out. I'm aware of this and as mentioned in the question, it is failing for the EU region only, but not the other regions like asia-northeast, etc.